# check whether port 80 is denied?

Tags: linux, nginx, iptables

I'm studying Iptables on linux, and try to reject all traffic coming to port 80.
I execute `iptables -A INPUT --dport 80 -j REJECT` on kali-linux.
But how can I testing the result that "all traffic to port 80 is rejected".
And what if allow traffic to port 80 and reject traffic going out through port 80.
I have Nginx on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check if port 80 is open.

1. Easiest way is to type `telnet myserver.com 80` from a remote computer. It tries to open a port 80 on server. It timeout if unable to open.
2. Use [netstat](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) to show the processes listening on TCP or UDP ports. Scan and grep for port-80.
   Something like this:
   `netstat -an | grep PORTNUMBER | grep -i listen`
   If you have an output, that means port 80 is open and listening.

Answer (score 0):

External way

**nmap example.com -p 80**

Internal way

**iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers**